# How to create multiple API requests based on different param values?

Tags: python, python-requests

So I have this list which stores different request URLS for finding an account.

```
accounts= []
```

Each url looks something like this.
`'https://example.somewebsite.ie:000/v12345/accounts/12345/users'`

Each URL has a different ID so the next URL in the list would be for example
`'https://example.somewebsite.ie:000/v12345/accounts/54321/users'`

I've tried doing something like this.

```
accountReq = []
for i in accounts:
    accountReq = requests.get(i, headers=headers).json()



for each in accountReq['data']:
    print(each['username']+" "+" ",each['first_name'],each['last_name'])
```

This only prints out the last GET requests data.

**How do I write multiple requests based on taking each different value in my list?**

I can do separate requests line by line but I don't want to do this as I may have a 100 plus URLS to try.

Comment: What error do you see? Iterating over a list of properly constructed URLs like that is fine

Comment: When I save a response , it only saves the response from one of the URLS. 
I need to save all responses from all URLS @LancelotduLac

Comment: You need to show more of your code to make this question relevant. I suspect you need a list (accountReq) to which you should append the responses otherwise accountReq will only ever contain the result of the last GET

Comment: sure, I will update now in a sec.

Comment: I see you updated your last comment, can you please post a coded example of how creating a list of responses should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accountReq` only holds the last data because you're redefining the variable on each iteration. You should change your code to this:

```
accountReq = []
for i in accounts:
    accountReq.append(requests.get(i, headers=headers).json())



for each in accountReq:
    account = each['data']
    for data in account:
        print(data['username']+" "+" ",data['first_name'],data['last_name'])
```

Now this will ADD every individual JSON object data to `accountReq` list.

Comment: This throws a ` for each in accountReq['data']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str ` error

Comment: @mrOlympia Edited the code. I think it should work now.

Comment: that didn't work but I tweaked it and it is working! I will post my answer and then accept yours.

Comment: I have looked at the code you provided and fixed my answer accordingly to eliminate any confusion for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in printing certain values then:

```
accounts = [] # a list of URLs

for account in accounts:
  (r := requests.get(account, headers=headers)).raise_for_status()
  for d in r.json()['data']:
    print(f"{d['username']}, {d['first_name']}, {d['last_name']}")
```

Comment: This throw this following error > print(f"{d['username']}, {d['first_name']}, {d['last_name']}")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @mrOlympia That's because r.json()['data'] is returning a list rather than a dictionary so your JSON structure is not as implied by your original code. I will edit my answer to account for that

Answer (score 0):

```
for each in accountReq:
        account = each['data']
        for data in account:
         print(data['username']+" "+" ",data['first_name'],data['last_name'])
```

that's what I done after tweaking an answer someone provided.